# What's the card-like feedback in the top or sidebar of google search?

Tags: google-api, google-search

If you search 'tomato' in google, i.e. https://google.co.uk/search?q=tomato 
There will be a card-like feedback as follows.
[image]
This feature is quite useful since it's more specific and relevant, which also responds to a variety of other things.

My question is what's the name of this feature? Is there any API exposed for it?

Basically, I want to find more about it.

Comment: Is this question improper to ask in this site? Why downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. After digging into Google Developer Docs, I find out this is called Knowledge Graph. Wikipedia has provided a decent introduction to it. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_Graph)